# Do you know of any product that uses the uCOS RTOS?

Tags: arm

For an assignment for uni I need to find consumer products using uC/OS by Micrium (currently Sillicon Labs). Can't find anything that's not from their customer stories.

I think it should be in Xerox printers but I couldn't find any.

Comment: this is basically a shopping question, which is not allowed here ... you are asking for a consumer product with a specific trait ... that trait could just as easily be a specific price

Comment: This is not related to IoT in my opinion. The embedded OS in question might used by some IoT product but the question itself is focusing on the "where" and "in what" instead of any IoT related aspect.

Answer (score 1):

Back in 2006 Microchip included uC/OS-II RTOS from Micrium in their MPLAB IDE. You might find some references to consumer products developed with it on the Microchip forums after that time, or ask a question on a forum.  This query returned 55 mentions of Micrium: [Microchip forum query](https://www.microchip.com/forums/search?searchid=3645983&phrase=Micrium&high=Micrium)